# How to Get The field value dynamically in python?

Tags: python, odoo, postgresql-9.1

I have a form view. I entered a value in a field. How can i retrieve that value and have it assigned to some variable in .py for making operations

For Example:
I have ActiveFrom field.I entered value 23-11-2011 to field in form view. I want to get that value dynamically in openerp. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you be more specific about this Form you're working on?

Comment: what could be considered for "dynamically in openerp", "field onchange", "save event" or any other event ? could you give some more details, so one could help with correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want the [`on_change` event](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_6_views_events/events/events.html#on-change). It lets you trigger server-side code when the user changes a field's value. You can then change the value of other fields, or pop up a warning message.

Here's an example of how to pop up a warning from the [warning module](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.0/view/head:/warning/warning.py?start_revid=4933#L58) (slightly edited):

```
def onchange_partner_id(self, cr, uid, ids, part):
    warning = {}
    title = False
    message = False
    partner = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr, uid, part)
    if partner.sale_warn != 'no-message':
        title =  _("Warning for %s") % partner.name
        message = partner.sale_warn_msg
        warning = {
                'title': title,
                'message': message,
        }

    result =  super(sale_order, self).onchange_partner_id(cr, uid, ids, part)
    return {'value': result.get('value',{}), 'warning':warning}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Don.How to return warning message from on_change.Can explain me with code please

Comment: There you go, @SantuSrinu, also read the documentation I linked to.